# Set up step_adjustment in aws_autoscaling_policy from variable in terraform

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am setting up a module to configure autoscaling in ASGs in terraform. Ideally, I'd like to pass in a list of maps to my module and have it loop through them, adding a step_adjustment for each map in the list to the policy, however this doesn't seem to work.

Current setup:

```
  name = "Example Auto-Scale Up Policy"
  policy_type = "StepScaling"
  autoscaling_group_name = "${aws_autoscaling_group.example_asg.name}"
  adjustment_type = "PercentChangeInCapacity"
  estimated_instance_warmup = 300
  step_adjustment {
    scaling_adjustment          = 20
    metric_interval_lower_bound = 0
    metric_interval_upper_bound = 5
  }
  step_adjustment {
    scaling_adjustment          = 25
    metric_interval_lower_bound = 5
    metric_interval_upper_bound = 15
  }
  step_adjustment {
    scaling_adjustment          = 50
    metric_interval_lower_bound = 15
  }
  min_adjustment_magnitude  = 4
}
```

I just want to provide the three `step_adjustments` as variables into my module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the way you can do it is as follows:

```
variable "step_adjustments" {
    type        = list(object({ metric_interval_lower_bound = string, metric_interval_upper_bound = string, scaling_adjustment = string }))
    default     = []
}

# inside your resource
resource "aws_appautoscaling_policy" "scale_up" {
  name = "Example Auto-Scale Up Policy"
  policy_type = "StepScaling"
  autoscaling_group_name = "${aws_autoscaling_group.example_asg.name}"
  adjustment_type = "PercentChangeInCapacity"
  estimated_instance_warmup = 300 
  dynamic "step_adjustment" {
    for_each = var.step_adjustments
    content {
      metric_interval_lower_bound = lookup(step_adjustment.value, "metric_interval_lower_bound")
      metric_interval_upper_bound = lookup(step_adjustment.value, "metric_interval_upper_bound")
      scaling_adjustment          = lookup(step_adjustment.value, "scaling_adjustment")
    }
  }
}

# example input into your module
step_adjustments = [
{
  scaling_adjustment          = 2
  metric_interval_lower_bound = 0
  metric_interval_upper_bound = 5
},
{
  scaling_adjustment          = 1
  metric_interval_lower_bound = 5
  metric_interval_upper_bound = "" # indicates infinity
}]
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer, clear and concise. Thank you so much, that worked perfectly!